# how to rollback data which is committed to database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2012

I have two tables Table1, Table2. Initially I need to insert one row in table1 and get the Id of the inserted row , use this Id in table2. But if there is any error while inserting data in table2, then table1 also needs to be roll backed. I am writing using statements but still this is not happening. This is what I tried

```
    using(cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
         cn.open()
          using (var cm = cn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cm.CommandText = Constants.InsertNewJob;  // inserts a job in table1
                    try
                    {
                        var jobId = Convert.ToInt32(cm.ExecuteScalar());

                        DataTable dt = QueueData.ToDataTable(); // queuedata contains large data which is converted to datatable
                        dt.Columns.Add("JobId", typeof(int), jobId.ToString()); // adding the retrieved jobId to datatable

                        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(cn))
                            {
                                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = Constants.DestinationTableName; //Table 2 which uses job id which is retrieved from Table 1
                                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("JobId", "JobId");
                                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("DateTime", "DateTime");
                                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                            }
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            Logger.Error(ex.Message, "Error while inserting data");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Logger.Error(ex.Message, "Error while inserting new job into transaction table");
                    }
                }
                cn.close()
        }
```

Still the data added into table1 is not getting roll backed if there is any error in table to bulk insert. Kindly help.
Thanks

Comment: The keyword here is transaction. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k2hy99x(v=vs.110).aspx. `using` statements don't magically rollback things on errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a [transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction(v=vs.110).aspx) to the SqlBulkCopy constructor.

```
using (SqlTransaction transaction = myConnection.BeginTransaction())
{
    using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(myConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, transaction))
    {
       try
       {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = Constants.DestinationTableName;
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("JobId", "JobId");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("DateTime", "DateTime");
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataSource);
            transaction.Commit();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Logger.Error(ex.Message, "Error while inserting data");
           transaction.Rollback();
       }
    }
}
```

See [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tchktcdk(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a **transaction**.
Have a look in the [MSDN website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/zayx5s0h(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2).

Brief example :

```
    // Start a local transaction.
    transaction = cn.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");

    // Must assign both transaction object and connection
    // to Command object for a pending local transaction
    command.Connection = cn;
    command.Transaction = transaction;

    // TRY to query the database
    // transaction.Commit();
```

Then use `transaction.Rollback();` in your **catch block**.

Comment: for precision sake: wrap (also) the transaction in a `using` statement, so it will be properly disposed in every case. When disposed the transaction will be rollbacked if it wasn't previoulsy committed